# TensorFlow on Windows: ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to make TensorFlow work on Windows. But after installation of Python 3.5 and TensorFlow, I keep getting the following error when I import the TensorFlow module:

```
>>>import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper

    "return importlib.import_module(mname)"
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper

    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
```

Please suggest what is missing from my end so that above runtime error can be removed.

Answer (score 8):

This error arises when one of the libraries (DLLs) on which TensorFlow depends cannot be found. To diagnose this kind of error, I have written a script that you can download [from here](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c); running the script will print suggestions about what steps to take to fix the error.

- If you are running the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, the most likely DLL to be missing is `MSVCP140.DLL`. It is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Update 3, which you can download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587).
- If you are running the GPU version of TensorFlow, it is possible that the CUDA libraries or the cuDNN libraries cannot be found. TensorFlow on Windows supports CUDA 8.0 (download from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)) and cuDNN 5.1 (download from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn)). Note that cuDNN is often installed to a different directory from CUDA, and you may need to manually add it to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

- just run below command it will clear all dependencies and then update it or remove and install the latest version of tensor flow(For CPU)
  This worked for me

`pip install tensorflow==1.5`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, your tool was awesome.  Turns out my CUDA 8.0 install had a slightly older version of cudnn64_5.dll instead of cudnn64_6.dll.