# Unable to run import tensorflow as tf

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow using the following command.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I am running a simple program which is

```
import tensorflow as tf
node1 = tf.constant(3.0, tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
print(node1, node2)
```

I am getting the following error on running the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have updated the pip and am running the program on python 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow on Windows: ImportError: No module named '\_pywrap\_tensorflow\_internal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751418/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal)

Answer (score 3):

This error message typically means that one of TensorFlow's dependencies cannot be found on your system. Since you are using the CPU-only version of TensorFlow on Windows, the most likely missing DLL is `msvcp140.dll`, which is required to run programs compiled using Microsoft Visual C++ 2015. This DLL is usually installed on developer machines as part of Visual Studio, or some Python distributions like Anaconda. However, the Python.org distribution of Python for Windows does not include it.

You can install `msvcp140.dll` on your system by downloading and installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

For others who find this answer, note that [this script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) can help to diagnose common TensorFlow on Windows installation issues.

Comment: would really appreciate if you can respond to this . 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498771/multilayer-encoder-output-state-to-multilayer-decoder-in-seq2seq-model-tf-1-0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, and probably as clueless as you about the error message, but as you are using python 3.x, shouldn't you have installed tensorflow by using:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

To see if you are using pip3 type:

```
pip3 -V
```

If you need more help, visit the official tutorial for [mac](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) or [linux](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux).

I hope this helps

dan4o

Comment: Tried installing by pip3 install tensorflow. Issue is not yet solved.

Comment: also, to print the values, i think you need to use session.run() or something similar. Check in the validate installation section (right at the bottom) of the tensorflow installation instructions. hope it helps