# TensorFlow on Windows CPU version: ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have followed all the instructions in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751418/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-no-module-named-pywrap-tensorflow-internal), i am using the latest version of tensor flow CPU version for windows gotten from 
[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) but i am still getting the module not found error, i ran the script in the previous answer and installed the latest version of Microsoft C++ Runtime
i have attached the error message any help would be appreciated

**stack trace**

```
    >>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", lin
e 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.p
y", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution. Althoug the setup worked on another computer, here I needed to install an older version of tensorflow.

- just run below command it will clear all dependencies and then update it. This worked for me

`pip install tensorflow==1.5`